# getView from BaseAdapter always return position=0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, gridview

As mentioned in topic. There is Base adapter implementation for `GridView` where during debug we can see that `onItemClick` is called with proper values like here:

[image]

... and just after this call is `getView` from `BaseAdapter` implementation which is called with:

[image]

There may be no dependency between these two, but anyway clicking on different elements on `GridView` should return different position values.

if `convertView != null` then  `convertView.getId();` returns -1 .

Any ideas appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is from adapter:

```
  public GridImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TileWidget> tileWidgetList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tileWidgetList = tileWidgetList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tileWidgetList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        TileWidget tw = tileWidgetList.get(position);
        return tw;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

The value returned by

public long getItemId(int position)

is ok.

**EDIT:**

Just debugged that is returns good `position` values when it is initialized. So the `zero'es` are only onClick results.

Comment: You have to post the code from the adapter. You're messing with the position index somewhere.

Comment: Why would you ever want to call `convertView.getId()`? This will return the `View` resource identifier. That is not the same as calling `BaseAdapter.getItemId(int position)`.

Comment: It's not used, just checked for  bad reason.. Still has no idea what to do. To worked it around and stored this.lastClickedItemsId = position;, when called getItem(int position), but I know It's not a good sollution.

Comment: @sandalone, plesae look on update.

Comment: i see a lot of place where people implement a custom variable for the data and override methods and rewirte the same code tat android framework already as, when the adapter as one inbuilt.. any specific reasons for tat?

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13603323/1680297 it helps me